# Vue Js Installation

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install

Tried installing vue js through

```
npm install -g @vue/cli.
```

My npm version is 6.14.4  and node version is 12.16.2

This is the error i am getting

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nEaUD\r\n=F4TR\r\n---'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sudesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-16T01_32_53_989Z-debug.log
```

I tried looking into the repo. I didn't understand what is the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `npm cache clean --force` and then run the `npm install -g @vue/cli` . I think this must solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try npm cache clean --force and then run the npm install -g @vue/cli  I think this must solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use the `npm cache clean --force` command in our terminal to delete all data from your cache folder after that run `npm install -g @vue/cli`. then run `vue create myapp` to create your vue CLI app

Answer (score 0):

1. Step : 1 `npm cache clean --force`
2. Step : 2 `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score -1):

clean npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`

if you are using mac or Linux try with `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`
for windows `npm install -g @vue/cli`